# Why isn't SSMS smart when it comes to adding columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

Whenever I want to add a column to a table it usually goes something like this:

1. Fire up SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
2. Select "Design" on the table I want to add the column to
3. Add the new column to the table
4. Save
5. Get an error that SSMS can't save because it would need to drop the table (and it can't because the the table has foreign keys on it).
6. Get frustrated that I forgot that this is something that SSMS can't do
7. Construct an alter table command by hand to add the column
8. Move on with life.

This time I am adding a step between numbers 6 and 7.  I thought I would ask why SSMS can't make a simple alter table statement to add my new column in.

(In case it matters I am running SSMS 2008 against SQL Server 2008.)

Comment: Because it's a piece of crap that we all must live with. (Once you use pgadmin3, SSMS just seems sad)

Comment: it always generates the CONSTRAINT drops for me, perhaps you have an option set that prevents this?

Comment: @KM, he said it generated the drop, but it won't drop due to foreign key constraints. What he(and I) wants to know is *why* it must drop the table to add a column

Comment: just out of curiosity - do you add the new column at the end of the table, or somewhere in between? SQL Server doesn't really have a concept of "column order" - so if you insert a new column in the middle of your table, all it can do is drop the old table, re-create the new table with the column order you want, and then copy the data over. If you have FK constraint on the table, step 1 will fail......

Comment: So moral of the story is: forget about SSMS' interactive designer and use T-SQL statements instead, and don't cling to column order - it's totally irrelevant for SQL, only relevant for humans. A T-SQL `ALTER TABLE xyz ADD newcolumnname` will (almost) always work - problem solved

Comment: As slow as SSMS is, I can usually write out the SQL to create the column faster than the design screen will show up. and yes, people that cling to the order of columns annoys me...

Comment: I always add it to the end.  I don't really care the order of the column (most times).

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can go to Tools-->Options-->Designers-->Table and Database Designers and uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"

Problem solved.

Here's an explanation from MSDN: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/956176.

> When you change a table so that you
>   alter the metadata structure of the
>   table, and then you save the table,
>   the table must be re-created based on
>   these changes.

Comment: @Alison: "@KM, he said it generated the drop, but it won't drop due to foreign key constraints. What he(and I) wants to know is why it must drop the table to add a column"

Comment: Ah, it is listed as "a bug" and they recommend using T-SQL to alter tables and not SSMS..

Comment: @Earlz: Do you have a link for the "Bug" listing?  If so post it as an answer.

Comment: @Vaccano, the link in this answer says it's a bug. The bad part is it has affected both 2005 and 2008 and Microsoft still doesn't seem to have intentions of fixing it.